# Use Loco translate for making Wordpress Multi-Langual

Tags: php, wordpress, multilingual

Recently i needed to translate a big website. I translated the Loco PO files with PO Editor.
Then i added it, and now i can have either the original language or the new one at a time.

Loco translate do not provide a solution for makeing a website multilangual.

But, on the Loco Translate official website it tells:
[image]

So there is a way to implement it with some coding.

Is there a ready snippet, or a proven working method to make Wordpress Multilangual with Loco Translate and some code snippet?

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the plugin description of you Loco Translate:

- Built-in translation editor within WordPress admin
- Create and update language files directly in your theme or plugin
- Extraction of translatable strings from your source code

https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/

Loco Translate is a really good plugin if you want to translate strings inside of your theme files or inside of plugins. For this use-case it works perfectly.

---

If you want to translate the content of your website, so the actual posts and pages with their text and images, you need something different. You do not want to translate strings in the source code, but the content of your pages/posts.

A free solution which I often use is Polylang. It is very easy and also supports custom post types, taxonomies, media, tags and much more, which you can activate or deactivate for translation. You can translate your content to as many languages as you like, a language switcher also is included. Content from one language can be automatically copied over so translating is fast and easy to manage. Really a recommendation from my side.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/